# How do you do an INDEX MATCH with two criteria on dates on Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to achieve this INDEX(Global!C5:C243; MATCH(A2; Global!A5:A243; 0); 0) which is working fine like this. But I would like to add two criteria in the match on dates Global!B5:B243 >= B1 and Global!B5:B243 < C1.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet if you are interested in arrayformula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Filter:

```
=index(filter(Global!C5:C243,A2= Global!A5:A243,Global!B5:B243 >= B1,Global!B5:B243 < C1),1)
```